# AscW equivalent from VB in C++

Tags: c++

I am using the function `AscW` (in VB6) to convert a unicode character into the character code.

I would like to know if there is an equivalent to this function in C++.

For example, I would like to get the value 32 from the character " ".

I would like to do the following:

```
wstring wstringToLower(wstring u)
{
    wstring s;

    for (int i=0;i<u.size();i++)
    {
        wstring sChar;
        sChar=u.substr(i,1);

        int iChar=static_cast<int>(sChar);

        int iNewChar=charCodeToLower(iChar);

        wstring sNewChar;
        sNewChar=wstring(iNewChar,1);

        s+=sNewChar;
    }

    return s;
}
```

The error "No conversion function found for std::wstring to int" is raised in the line

```
 int iChar=static_cast<int>(sChar);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast to `int`:

```
int main()
{
    std::wstring u = L"abc";

    std::wstring sChar = u.substr(1, 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < sChar.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(sChar[i]);
}
```

Comment: I have also edited my post. Can you have a look? Your code only works if I add .c_str(), but then it results in a weird char code.

Comment: Your code is not working for me. I get the error "No conversion function found for std::wstring to int". Does it really work for you or did you write that on the fly?

Comment: @tmighty: the code works for me. You must have mistyped something because `sChar[i]` will be of type `wchar_t`, not `std::wstring`.

Comment: @tmighty Your edited post shows `static_cast<int>(sChar)` instead of `static_cast<int>(sChar[i])`. That's wrong.